# Print Multiple Selected Documents in View via Web lotus domino

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

i would like to print selected documents in a view in a way that each document are compiled in a single print. It's like 1 document on page 1 and second document on page 2. I after  i print this documents they would be flagged as printed and then i would be able to export them to a notepad text file. I need to do this in Lotus domino in a web based applications. Answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more you do not get native view in the web.In Web every thing is HTML as you know.Are you saying that you want to print the documents that you are seeing in list in a browser for example seeing to email in a browser? You have a list in web and you want to select documents and print them?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native Lotus Domino print command to print documents selected from the web. This is not an uncommon problem in other technologies either. Once you're using the browser, you are stuck with the browsers capabilities for printing as you would with any other technology, unless the server can generate the content for the print out, say as a PDF or HTML/CSS.

There are a number of ways to do this. The easiest approach I can conceive still requires quite a bit of coding though. There may be other solutions, but it depends what your skill set is.

Others have been trying to solve this problem. You can try [this](http://quintessens.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/printing-documents-from-a-view-web/) un-tested solution, or [here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/answer/How-to-print-selected-documents-from-embedded-view), (but you have to register for free), or [here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Recreating-print-view-on-the-Web) to, or you can "roll your own". Knowing which document has been selected can be found like [this](http://www.leadershipbynumbers.com/ms.nsf/d6plinks/BMMA-5XGSFH)

If you have some experience with producing HTML. You can "rollYourOwn" by creating an agent (called "printSelectedDocuments"), that accepts the UNID's of the selected documents from the view, and then constructs a web page that presents the combined documents for printing.

You can can control the HTML output to the browser from an agent using [this](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4PSGWL) technique. There is one commercial API you can use, [PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/lotus.htm). But this still requires a lot of coding, but may take some hassle out of the process.

If you elect to write your own agent, the agent will have to loop through each selected document, and generate the HTML page with the layout of each field you want to print and manage your page breaks. If you really need granular control you can try [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) in a java agent and stream back the PDF to the browser. A google around the interwebs indicates that no one has a simple solution.